# How to build differently a descriptive statistics table by using the gtsummary library

Tags: r, gtsummary

I've build the following descriptive statistics table for the dataset I'm working on:

[image]

And I've obtained it by using the code you could find here.

```
sum_stats = function(data, group, value, alpha=0.05)data %>%
  group_by(!!enquo(group)) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    q1 = quantile(!!enquo(value),1/4,8),
    min = min(!!enquo(value)),
    mean = mean(!!enquo(value)),
    median = median(!!enquo(value)),
    q3 = quantile(!!enquo(value),3/4,8),
    max = max(!!enquo(value)),
    sd = sd(!!enquo(value)),
    stderr = sd/sqrt(n),
    kurtosis = e1071::kurtosis(!!enquo(value)),
    skewness = e1071::skewness(!!enquo(value)),
    LCL = mean - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n - 1) * stderr,
    UCL = mean + qt(1 -(0.05 / 2), n - 1) * stderr,
    #SW.stat = ShapiroTest(!!enquo(value), alpha)$statistic,
    #SW.p = ShapiroTest(!!enquo(value), alpha)$p.value,
    #SW.test = ShapiroTest(!!enquo(value), alpha)$test,
    nout = length(boxplot.stats(!!enquo(value))$out)
  )

nested_out <- out %>% 
  mutate(COND = factor(COND)) %>%
  group_by(signals) %>% 
  nest() 

stats_nested <- nested_out %>% group_by(signals) %>%
  mutate(stats = map(data, ~sum_stats(.x, COND, value))) %>% 
  unnest(stats) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-'data') %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  merge_v(j = 'signals') %>% 
  colformat_double(digits = 2)
```

If I would like to obtain quitre the same output, by using the `gtsummary() package`, what should I do?

Here you could find a short extract of the the dataset

```
structure(list(ID = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01"), GR = c("RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP"), SES = c("V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V"), COND = c("NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR"), signals = c("P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", 
"P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", "LPPearly(500-700).Cz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Pz"), value = c(-11.6312151716924, -5.16524399006139, 
11.8802266972569, -11.7785042972793, -5.96429031525769, 8.23981597718437
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Thanks in advance for those who will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gtsummary package will typically place multiple statistics in a single column. If you'd like each statistic in a separate column, you can iterate your calls to `tbl_summary()` for each summary statistics. You will then have a list of `tbl_summary()` objects, and you can merge them with `tbl_merge()` into a single table. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

# iterate over summary statistics
c("mean", "sd", "min", "max") %>%
  lapply(
    function(.x) {
      tbl_summary(
        data = trial, 
        statistic = everything() ~ paste0("{", .x, "}"),
        include = c(age, marker),
        missing = "no"
      ) %>%
        modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ glue::glue("**{.x}**"))
    }
  ) %>%
  # merge all tables to get one column per summary statistic
  tbl_merge() %>%
  # remove the default headers and footnotes
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **mean** | **sd** | **min** | **max** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 47 | 14 | 6 | 83 |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.92 | 0.86 | 0.00 | 3.87 |

<sup>Created on 2021-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Mmm...I've tried to replace the interesting variable but it does not work

Comment: as you could in my sample table there are two factor variables (signals and for each signals different conditions) in the proper example you've suggest it should be taken into account also this. Thanks

Comment: Good evening, I though that the best thing to do is to pass dataset to a wide format. However iI didn't figure out yet how to group those statistics per every CONDITIONS (actually, three).